# optimize a loop that loops over billion times in python

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

i have a list with 170 length.
and i want to save all of it's 5 length combinations nCr(170, 5) in a file.
so it's about 1,115,034,284 and i use code below to generate combinations.

```
import itertools
all_texts = [] # my list with length 170
all_combinations = []
for subset in itertools.combinations(all_texts, 5):
    text = ""
    for sub in subset:
        text += sub + " && "

    query = text[0:-3]
    all_combinations.append(query)


filename = "filename.txt"
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for item in all_combinations:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

but this is a huge loop which my server with 128 Gb RAM capacity is unable to do without memory exception error.
how can i optimize this loop?
thanks.

Comment: Remove the string concatenation to gain some performance the sacrifice performance for memory by writing to the file multiple times instead of saving everything in `all_combinations`

Comment: base problem is in first loop

Comment: @user15450241 it's not (`combinations` returns an iterator), unless you are using Python 2.

Comment: `all_combinations.append(query)` could rather be `f.write("%s\n" % query)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def addition(a):
    return "&&".join(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    all_texts = []  # my list with length 170
        
    a = itertools.combinations(all_texts, 5)
    combinations = list(map(addition, a))
    open('filename.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(combinations))
```

Comment: this solution occures memory error as well !